# Error in Obiee while creating a graph: Exceeded configured maximum number of allowed output prompts, sections, rows, or columns

Tags: oracle, analysis, obiee

I am using Oracle Business Intelligence and I was trying to create an analysis that contains a table and a graph. I get the table normally, but when I try to add a new view that is a graph, I get the following error:

> Exceeded configured maximum number of allowed output prompts,
>   sections, rows, or columns.

What can I do to solve this issue? Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the documentation or googled? Because over in the actual Oracle forums we get this question at least twice a month and there are literally dozens of answered threads.

Comment: Chris, yes I did search for a solution over the Internet before posting it here. Most of them suggest to edit instanceconfig.xml file, but is that the only one solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application has default settings which are probably not sufficient for you so you will have to review WHAT you can change and how high you want to push the settings.

The documentation has all the details: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/biee/BIESG/GUID-FF6954BA-2DE0-4422-BA58-05F32936F4FF.htm#BIESG1719

Comment: Thank you, Chris, I will try that too

Answer (score 2):

OBI has maximums based on usual graph and dashboard usage, please double check if the detail level is really necessary. Sometimes a top N using [selection steps](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/biee/BIEUG/GUID-663B5A97-06B1-4486-8C5E-4261B1758581.htm#GUID-26884876-2045-4A02-B62A-A298A400002D) or breaking the analysis into a series of [master detail](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/biee/BIEUG/GUID-843DD4CA-B575-4752-82DE-831768C1215D.htm#GUID-4C5675A3-0353-4807-9048-16FF9FEF5CB8) or [action-linked](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/biee/BIEUG/GUID-63576665-7BFE-4D1E-ABB9-51B8AAFBB940.htm#BIEUG644) analyses is better for performance and navigation.

If you absolutely MUST show that many values, the configuration can be changed using the link that @Chris provided

1. Open the instanceconfig.xml file for editing, located in: 
   BI_DOMAIN/config/fmwconfig/biconfig/OBIPS
2. Locate the Table, Pivot, Trellis, Charts, Narrative, Ticker, and Treemap parent sections, in which you must add the elements that are described in the table below.
3. Include the elements and their ancestor elements as appropriate, as shown in the following example:

instanceconfig.xml

```
<ServerInstance>
  <Views>
      <Table>
        <MaxCells>10000</MaxCells>
        <MaxPagesToRollOutInDelivery>1000</MaxPagesToRollOutInDelivery>
        <MaxVisiblePages>1000</MaxVisiblePages>
        <MaxVisibleRows>500</MaxVisibleRows>
        <MaxVisibleSections>25</MaxVisibleSections>
        <DefaultRowsDisplayed>30</DefaultRowsDisplayed>
        <DefaultRowsDisplayedInDelivery>250</DefaultRowsDisplayedInDelivery>
        <DefaultRowsDisplayedInDownload>65000</DefaultRowsDisplayedInDownload>
        <DefaultRowsDisplayedInDownloadCSV>65000</DefaultRowsDisplayedInDownloadCSV>
      </Table>
      <Pivot>
        <MaxPagesToRollOutInDelivery>1000</MaxPagesToRollOutInDelivery>
        <MaxVisibleColumns>300</MaxVisibleColumns>
        <MaxVisiblePages>1000</MaxVisiblePages>
        <MaxVisibleRows>500</MaxVisibleRows>
        <MaxVisibleSections>25</MaxVisibleSections>
        <DefaultRowsDisplayed>30</DefaultRowsDisplayed>
        <DefaultRowsDisplayedInDelivery>250</DefaultRowsDisplayedInDelivery>
        <DefaultRowsDisplayedInDownload>65000</DefaultRowsDisplayedInDownload>
              </Pivot>
      <Trellis>
        <Simple>
            <MaxCells>1000</MaxCells>
            <MaxVisibleSections>10</MaxVisibleSections>
            <MaxVisiblePages>1000</MaxVisiblePages>
            <MaxVisibleRows>100</MaxVisibleRows>
            <MaxVisibleColumns>75</MaxVisibleColumns>
            <MaxPagesToRollOutInDelivery>1000</MaxPagesToRollOutInDelivery>
            <DefaultRowsDisplayed>10</DefaultRowsDisplayed>
            <DefaultRowsDisplayedInDelivery>100</DefaultRowsDisplayedInDelivery>
            <DefaultRowsDisplayedInDownload>6500</DefaultRowsDisplayedInDownload>
        </Simple>
        <Advanced>
            <MaxCells>5000</MaxCells>
            <MaxVisibleSections>50</MaxVisibleSections>
            <MaxVisiblePages>1000</MaxVisiblePages>
            <MaxVisibleRows>250</MaxVisibleRows>
            <MaxVisibleColumns>150</MaxVisibleColumns>
            <MaxPagesToRollOutInDelivery>1000</MaxPagesToRollOutInDelivery>
            <DefaultRowsDisplayed>25</DefaultRowsDisplayed>
            <DefaultRowsDisplayedInDelivery>250</DefaultRowsDisplayedInDelivery>
            <DefaultRowsDisplayedInDownload>10000</DefaultRowsDisplayedInDownload>
        </Advanced>
      </Trellis>
      <Charts>
        <MaxVisibleColumns>2000</MaxVisibleColumns>
        <MaxVisiblePages>1000</MaxVisiblePages>
        <MaxVisibleRows>2000</MaxVisibleRows>
        <MaxVisibleSections>25</MaxVisibleSections>
        <JavaHostReadLimitInKB>4096</JavaHostReadLimitInKB>
      </Charts>
      <Narrative>
        <MaxRecords>40000</MaxRecords>
        <DefaultRowsDisplayed>30</DefaultRowsDisplayed>
      </Narrative>
      <Ticker>
        <MaxRecords>40000</MaxRecords>
      </Ticker>
      <Treemap>
        <MaxCells>5000</MaxCells>
        <MaxVisiblePages>10000</MaxVisiblePages>
        <MaxVisibleRows>10000</MaxVisibleRows>
        <MaxVisibleSections>50</MaxVisibleSections>
      </Treemap>
  </Views>
</ServerInstance>
```